# How to send Authorization header in Android using Volley library?

Tags: android, android-volley

How can I send `Authorization` header using Volley library in Android for `GET` method?

This is my request code:

```
JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d("Response", response.toString());
            pd.dismiss();
            
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("Error", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            pd.dismiss();

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Authorization", "2e96e0a4ff05ba86dc8f778ac49a8dc0");
            return headers;
        }
    };
```

Comment: You already are sending your authorization header using Map<T,T> getHeaders().

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: i got this Error: com.android.volley.ServerErro

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, YourUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        if (!response.equals(null)) {
            Log.e("Your Array Response", response);                    
        } else {
            Log.e("Your Array Response", "Data Null");
        }
    }

}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e("error is ", "" + error);
    }
}) {    

 //This is for Headers If You Needed
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        params.put("token", ACCESS_TOKEN);
        return params;
    }

 //Pass Your Parameters here
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("User", UserName);
        params.put("Pass", PassWord);
        return params;
    }
};
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
queue.add(request);
```

Comment: When I use TLS(Https) encryption serverside and send the token as Authorization Header like ("Authorization: Basic xyzToken"), is the token transmitted in encrypted form?

Answer (score 13):

Try following code:

```
@Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        String credentials = "username" + ":" + "password";
        String base64EncodedCredentials = Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Authorization", "Basic " + base64EncodedCredentials);
        return headers;
    }
```

Comment: public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)  ----it gives error null

Comment: Did you replaced "username" and "password" string with your auth variables?

Comment: again same public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) ----it gives error nul

Answer (score 3):

This can be simply achieved by using the getHeaders() thus;

```
@Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headerMap.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                headerMap.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + ACCESS_TOKEN);
                return headerMap;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

1.Try using getBodyContentType()::

```
     JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Log.d("Response", response.toString());
        pd.dismiss();

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        VolleyLog.d("Error", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        pd.dismiss();

    }
}) 
{
     @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Authorization", "2e96e0a4ff05ba86dc8f778ac49a8dc0");
        return headers;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If an API needs a Authorization Header then Using Volley we need to do this :

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObejct = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            Log.wtf("The Response ",response.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Authorization", "XXXX");
            return params;
        }
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 @Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    String credentials = preferenceHelper.getEmail() + ":" + preferenceHelper.getPassword();
    String base64EncodedCredentials = Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("Authorization", "Basic " + base64EncodedCredentials);
    return headers;
}
```